# Generate .jtl(for analysis) and .csv(for report) files after Jmeter test in non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In non GUI mode, is there a way to generate both .jtl file and .csv file under below circumstance:

**.jtl** would be required to store and analyse response data in case of failure which demands

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
```

At the same time **.csv** is required to generate HTML report which demands

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

It seems that either of these only can be generated at a time.
Is there a way around? I want to be able to store response data as well as generate reports. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of JMeter 5.3 it's possible to use [only CSV results file format](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#overview) for HTML reporting dashboard generation.

[image]

If you need to store response data in case of failure just add a separate [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) to your test plan like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) and choose what and where to store:

[image]